# SIGSEGV when trying to open tiff with gdal

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdal, fault, geotiff, osgeo

All I am trying to do it run the basic command:

```
from osgeo import gdal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gdal.Open(<filepath>)
```

This gives the following undescriptive output:

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered.

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I can open other `.tif` files. The file that I am trying to open is population data from https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/57753ebee4b07dd077c70868. I also found that I cannot open population data from WorldPop, getting the same output.

I have GDAL 3.3.3, which seems to be the only version I can successfully install, and libtiff 4.3.0. I am on macOS Big Sur 11.6 and using Python 3.7. How can I go about resolving or debugging this issue?

---UPDATE 2022-01-10---

I found out that it is a problem with Pycharm. It runs fine if I run the script outside of Pycharm. It also runs fine within Pycharm on a separate install on my Windows machine (as opposed to Mac). So, the question has now turned into, why does this break when running with Pycharm on a Mac?

Comment: Which file are you trying to open, I tried the 2010 population data GeoTIFF and it works for me

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I forgot to update, but it turns out it was an issue with Pycharm. I still do not know why it breaks, though. I've resorted to running on a different computer. It seems to work with my Windows installation as opposed to my Mac installation.